# Pass struct member array to function in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

```
static void fill_array(int arr[], int count, int num)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = num;
    }    
}

typedef struct
{
    int a[10];
} x;

int main(void) {
    x *x1;
    fill_array(x1->a, 10, 0);
}
```

While trying this I am getting Runtime error. Can anybody help on this issue? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't allocate any memory for `x`: the behaviour of your program is *undefined*.

For this example, you could get away with

```
x x1;
fill_array(x1.a, 10, 0);
```

i.e. use automatic storage duration for `x`. This is because `x1.a` effectively decays to a pointer when passed to the function `fill_array`.

Answer (score 1):

You have not allocated memory for x1.

```
int main(void) {
    x *x1 = malloc(sizeof(x));

    if(0 !=x1)
    {
        fill_array(x1->a, 10, 0);
        free(x1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for checking the return value of `malloc`. Have an upvote.

Comment: you are using `x` and `x1` inconsistently

Comment: Thanks  BLUEPIXY and  artm. It was a typo and i corrected it.

Answer (score -1):

Your runtime error should be probably a `segmentation fault`

I can look your first pointeur `x *x1;`

Wich is not allocated and you are trying to access to the content of a non-allocated pointeur so ... segfault.

There is 2 solution.
declare your structure with local memory `x x1;`
or allocate it

Comment: The runtime error can be anything. The pointer itself is allocated, but is not initialised.